# Android HCE application architecture

Tags: android, android-activity, architecture, android-service, hce

I'm currently working on android HCE application. My `HCE service` takes APDUs from reader device. Reader device sends them continuously. So `processCommandApdu()` in my `HCE service` gets called quite often. Most of time `READER_STATE_APDU` comes. This is a proprietary apdu and is only recognized by reader device and my android `HCE service`. It contains some info about reader and special `MESSAGE` byte. Most of time `MESSAGE` byte is 0x00 what means no messages. But sometimes it indicates some event. It may be an error or something else. My `HCE service` must confirm `MESSAGE` byte in response APDU. And reader device clears `MESSAGE` byte when received response APDU from my `HCE service`.

Now my idea is to parse `READER_STATE_APDU` in `processCommandApdu()` method and show corresponding `Activity` to user.

For example, when `MESSAGE` byte is 0x00 I want to start `ReaderActivity` to show reader's info to user. And when `MESSAGE` byte is `SOME_ERROR` I want to start `ErrorActivity` to show error to user.

So my `processCommandApdu()` may be like this (**pseudocode**):

```
public byte[] processCommandApdu( byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras )
{
    ...

    if commandApdu is READER_STATE_APDU
    {
        if messageByte is NO_MESSAGE
        {
            create intent for ReaderActivity and start it
        }
        else if messageByte is SOME_ERROR
        {
            create intent for ErrorActivity and start it
        }
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Of course these activities should have corresponding launch modes or flags in intents.

But as I said earlier, `MESSAGE` byte is `SOME_ERROR` only for one transaction and I want to show `ErrorActivity` to user for a some time and prevent `ReaderActivity` from being started.

So I can imagine following code in my `HCE service` (**pseudocode**):

```
boolean mStartReaderActivity;

...

public byte[] processCommandApdu( byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras )
{
    ...

    if commandApdu is READER_STATE_APDU
    {
        if messageByte is NO_MESSAGE
        {
            if ( mStartReaderActivity )
            {
                create intent for ReaderActivity and start it
            }
        }
        else if messageByte is SOME_ERROR
        {
            if ( mStartReaderActivity )
            {
                mStartReaderActivity = false;
            }

            create intent for ErrorActivity and start it
        }
        ...
    }

    ...
}

...

public int onStartCommand( Intent intent, int flags, int startId )
{
    if intent is INTENT_ERROR_CONFIRMED
    {
        mStartReaderActivity = true;
    }
}
```

and in my `ErrorActivity` (**pseudocode**):

```
public void onConfirmErrorButtonClick()
{
    create INTENT_ERROR_CONFIRMED and start service
}
```

But this solution seems to be unreliable. I could, for example, use `SharedPreferences` to retain `mStartReaderActivity` across my `HCE service` recreation (**pseudocode**):

```
boolean mStartReaderActivity;

...

public void onCreate()
{
    ...
    loadStartActivityFromPreferences();
    ...
}

public byte[] processCommandApdu( byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras )
{
    ...

    if commandApdu is READER_STATE_APDU
    {
        if messageByte is NO_MESSAGE
        {
            if ( mStartReaderActivity )
            {
                create intent for ReaderActivity and start it
            }
        }
        else if messageByte is SOME_ERROR
        {
            if ( mStartReaderActivity )
            {
                mStartReaderActivity = false;
                saveStartActivityToPreferences();
            }

            create intent for ErrorActivity and start it
        }
        ...
    }

    ...
}

...

public int onStartCommand( Intent intent, int flags, int startId )
{
    if intent is INTENT_ERROR_CONFIRMED
    {
        mStartReaderActivity = true;
        saveStartActivityToPreferences();
    }
}
```

But there is no guaranty that `INTENT_ERROR_CONFIRMED` will be created and sent and delivered. For example, Android can kill process before user pushed the button. So `HCE service` may stuck with `mStartReaderActivity==false`.

Is there any way to deal with it?

Or maybe should I change architecture? For example, should I use one `Activity` with `Fragments` and retain `mStartReaderActivity (well, mShowReaderFragment in new terms)` in `Activity` via `savedINstanceState`?

Or maybe some other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want exactly, but if you want to show `ErrorActivity` until user click on button.

HCE Server (it's pseudo code):

```
public byte[] processCommandApdu( byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras )
{
    if commandApdu is READER_STATE_APDU {
        if messageByte is NO_MESSAGE {
            if(SharedPrefs 'inError != true'){
                create intent for ReaderActivity and start it
            }
        } else if messageByte is SOME_ERROR {
            save 'inError = true + errorMessage=myerror' in SharedPref
            create intent for ErrorActivity and start it
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // set error to false
    SharedPrefs 'inError = false'
}
```

In ErrorActivity (it's pseudo code)

```
//click on button acknowledge
public void clickAcknowledgeError(View v){
    save 'inError = false'
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for answer. But I think that your solution is similar to my (see `saveStartActivityToPreferences()` and `loadStartActivityFromPreferences()` in my question) and, if so, it is not working. For example, `HCE service` got `ERROR` and set (and save to prefs) flag. Then `ErrorActivity` started and shown to user. Then Android kills process and user does not push button and, if so, flag is not cleared. Then `HCE service` gets restarted and read flag from preferences. Now flag alway indicates that `ReaderActivity` should not be started

Comment: I'm really sorry for my absence for so long time. Thank you for your comment. But this solution also seems to be unreliable. If, say, OS kills entire process, onDestroy won't be called. And error_state won't be cleared. Vice versa, if NFC link drops down (even for a short time), onDestroy gets called and error_state gets cleared early.

Comment: I really think that my problem is architecture related. Service shall report all events and not filter them. I think I shall use only one activity with fragments and store error_state in activity's instance_state. Please comment this assumption. Also I don't know if I should post it as answer to my own question.